# Is playing backgammon Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, game, gambling

There is a  hadith from Burayda by Imam Muslim in his Sahih,
"Whoever plays *Backgammon* is as one who dipped his hand in swine's blood".

I gather from this that, games of chance & playing with dice may be Haram. Is this true/correct?

> "O ye who believe! Intoxicants and gambling, (dedication of) stones,
>   and (divination by) arrows, are an abomination― of Satan's handiwork:
>   eschew such (abomination), that ye may prosper."
>
> Surah Al Ma'idah Ayah 90

Isn't the admonishment in the Qur'an against Gambling only? And surely this means with property or money.

Otherwise, Snakes & Ladders, a game children play with dice would be Haram.

Comment: No dice or chess is incorrect translation, نرد or نردشير is backgammon, and it would be makrooh to play not haram, haram only when played for money (gambling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as gambling is not involved, the only possible criteria can be "wasted time," which is, of course, nothing special to backgammon.

Comment: blackened, please help me here [What exactly is considered gambling in the case of professional sports/gaming or any sports/gaming involving luck/chance?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67167/what-exactly-is-considered-gambling-in-the-case-of-professional-sports-gaming-or)

Answer (score 3):

Extracts taken from fatwa:

> Abu Dawood (4938) and Ibn Maajah (3762) narrated from Abu Moosa
>   al-Ash’ari that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah
>   be upon him) said: “Whoever plays with dice has disobeyed Allaah and
>   His Messenger.” Classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood.

...

> It was also narrated by Ahmad (19519) in the words: “Whoever plays
>   with cubes (dice) has disobeyed Allaah and His Messenger.” Classed as
>   hasan by al-Arna’oot in Tahqeeq al-Musnad.

Fatwa source: http://islamqa.info/en/ref/95409